# Facebook Face Pile Using HTML5 Instead of iFrame

Tags: javascript, facebook

Is it possible to use a Facebook Face Pile pointing to an APP-ID instead of a HREF through the JavaScript API? For example, what would the JavaScript equivalent of the iFrame code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/facepile.php?app_id=120600291315567"
  style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height: 70px">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To show how many friends are **using** your website/app, just use the HTML5 example generated at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/ and then *remove* the `data-href` attribute.  Example:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId= 120600291315567";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-facepile" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>
```

The `data-href` attribute signifies that you want to show how many people have *liked* that specific URL instead.

Answer (score -2):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId= 120600291315567";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-facepile" data-href="http://example.com" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>
```

this actually shown in the social plugin docs in facebook.

Comment: This code is to create a FacePile for a page (not an application). The faces that are displayed will be different...